# writeUnshared writes the fields like writeObject

Tags: java, serialization

So I have a wrapper class like this:

```
class VeryWrapper
{
    Wrapper wrp = new Wrapper();
    int val = 0;
}
```

Where `Wrapper` is defined as:

```
class Wrapper
{
    int val = 0;
}
```

Now, if I wanted to serialize it into a stream, change both `val` and `wrp.val`, and serialize it with the new state. I understand that using `writeObject` would cause the old state to be received in the other side of the stream. So one has to use `writeUnshared` in this case. But the problem is that using this method only the object itself will be unshared, not its fields (`wrp` field I mean), and so the value of `val` will be updated, but the value of `wrp.val` would still be the old value. How would you get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Its a good idea to call `reset()` periodicially to avoid a memory leak.  In your case it will ensure that all object will be sent again.

Comment: I know, this was my approach too, but this will slow down the operation. Do you think there might be a better way, maybe not having to rewrite everything that's already been serialized?

Comment: Another option is to send a different object each time.

Comment: Or copying it, or making it immutable and only replacing it.